# PHP my math doesnt work and my vairable shows 0 but it is something else

Tags: php, sql, math

So my problem is i`ve set Variables at the beginning og my Script and later in the script i need that variable to do some math so it knows if it has money to buy something and if it has no money to buy the items. so heres my script

The error shows up all the way on the bottom of the script.

```
    $user = 'Ramon';

// get integer data from url
$removeslash = "/xampp/";
$actual_link3 = "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$actual_link2 = str_replace($removeslash,"",$actual_link3);
$actual_link = str_replace(".php","",$actual_link2);
echo $actual_link;
// connect to mysql database
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password, $database);
if (!$conn) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Bedrijf WHERE ID='".$actual_link."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$NaamBedrijf = $row['Name'];
$WorthNow = $row['WorthNow'];

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='".$user."'");
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$Aandelen = $row2['Shares'.$actual_link];
$Money = $row2['Money'];
echo "IK HRB NU".$Aandelen;
//Waarde aandelen berkenen
$WaardePort = $Aandelen * $WorthNow;

//Geld formateren van 1293384 naar $1,293,384.00
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
$MoneyFOR = money_format('%(#10n', $Money) . "\n";
$WaardePort = money_format('%(#10n', $WaardePort) . "\n";
$WaardeNU = money_format('%(#10n', $WorthNow) . "\n";

echo "AANDELEN:".$Aandelen;

echo "<html>
<head>
<title>Beurs</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='index.css'/>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<td width='992px'>
<p class='ingelogd'>Je bent ingelogd Als ".$user."</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width='992px'>
<p>Er staat ".$MoneyFOR." Dollar op je bank.</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table><br/>
<table>
<tr>
<td id='Title' width='992px'>Je Kunt Informatie zien over je aandelen en aandelen verkopen/kopen.</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width='1000px'>
  <tr>
    <td>".$NaamBedrijf."</td>
    <td>".$WaardeNu."</td>
    <td>".$Aandelen."</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <form>
    <td>Kopen of Verkopen?</td>
    <td>
    <input type='radio' name='1' value='1'>Verkopen</input>
    <input type='radio' name='2' value='2'>Kopen</input><br/>
    </td>
    <td>Aantal andelen:<input style='width:85px;' type='text' name='Totaal'/><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Koop/Verkoop'/></td>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td width='992px'><label>Je aandelen zijn ".$WaardePort." Dollar Waard.</label><input type='submit' name='back' value='Ga Terug naar overzicht'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>";

echo "AANDELEN:".$Aandelen;

if($_GET){
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    if(isset($_GET['1'])){
        echo "Aandelen totaal:".$_GET['Totaal'];
        echo "Hoeveel aandelen heb ik: ".$Aandelen;

        if (!$_GET['Totaal'] > $Aandelen) { //ERROR IS HERE AND BELOW

            echo "<center><p style='color:red; font-weight:bold;'>je hebt niet zoveel andelen!</p></center>";
        }else{
        $jekrijgt = $WorthNow * $_GET['Totaal'];
            $Aandelen = $Aandelen - $_GET['Totaal'];
            $Money = $jekrijgt + $Money;
            echo "Je hebt ".$_GET['Totaal']." Aandelen Verkocht Voor: ".$Money;
            echo $Aandelen;
        }
    }else{
        echo "BUY"; 
    }

    }
}
?>
```

**EXPLAINATION !**

When  echo the Variable aandelen before the If statements it Shows up perfectly fine but when i try to do some math to mae it when it doesnt have that much Shares(aandelen) then it will echo You dont have that much Shares. But it always echo That you have sold shares even if you dont have that much shares.

To see whats going wrong check http://wirechat.net16.net/xampp/5.php

Answer (score 0):

`!$_GET['Totall']` is processed before the `>` operator.

This means that it will only ever (numerically) be zero (if `Totall` is truthy), or one (if `Totall` is empty or zero).

The correct way to negate `>` is by using `<=` instead.

```
if( $_GET['Totaal'] <= $Aandelen)
```

Comment: This doesnt realy help because i already had it like that but that didnt work either. It always says that i sold Shares but When i fill in a number greater then that i have it still says You sold .... Aandelen